# DOM PDF renders on mac but not PC

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, dompdf

I'm using DOM PDF to convert a simple html page to a PDF--everything works on mac, but on PC I get the message: [image: PDF error on windows]

Is there a log I can check? What could make this work on mac (using preview) but not adobe on windows?

*Edit*

As bfavaretto suggested, I opened the PDF in textedit. Here's the error:

```
<p>Message:  Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated</p>
<p>Filename: lib/class.pdf.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 4332</p>
```

Here is my CI code:

```
function pdf($id)
    {
        // Setup fields
        $this->load->helper('htm_to_pdf');
        $data['data'] = $this->home_model->getReport(array('id'=>$id));
        $html = $this->load->view('HTML2PDF/Code/index', $data, true);
        pdf_create($html, 'filename');
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer as I misinterpreted question.

Comment: You don't say what version you're using, but have you tried upgrading to the latest version of DOMPDF? That fixed the issue I had a while back. I remember upgrading to the current beta at the time, which might help. I forget which version, though.

Comment: I cant read that message(image) clearly, maybe im just getting old :)

Comment: Do you mean Mac vs Windows as *clients*, or *servers*?

Comment: Can you post the PHP code you're using to call DOMPDF?

Comment: @bfavaretto, as clients...the PDF just won't open on windows.

Comment: @jsuissa, I haven't changed anything except the PDF template that is rendered...

Comment: You could try to open the PDF on a text editor (or Notepad). If some PHP error occurred, it will be a HTML containing the error message, instead of a PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some wiki [usage](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage) information

```
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");


$html_to_string = $this->load->view('', array(), true);


$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html_to_string);

force_download('sample.pdf', file_get_contents($dompdf->render()));
```

-

Instead of force download you could use

```
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

Comment: Ahh. Would it be better practice to force download like your middle example?

Comment: personally I prefer to render pdf's in the browser and let the user decide if he/she wants to download it, unfortunatly they would need to have a pdf reader plugin in their browser of choice.  If you just want to save a copy for yourself then sure you can force download it.  You would need to create the pdf first. $pdf = pdf_create('', ''); force_download($pdf, file_get_contents($pdf)) //need to load download helper first.   Also looks like your copy of DOM PDF is out-dated(from the error above). Grab yourself an updated version

Comment: Philip, almost there...I'm getting an error: `Message: file_get_contents(  ): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` when using your code...it renders, but with errors.

Comment: @KevinBrown morning kevin, update your version of dom pdf, ive updated my answer, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`set_magic_quotes_runtime` is not used anymore in dompdf 0.6. I suggest you to download the latest version (0.6 beta 3) or to remove the `set_magic_quotes_runtime` call in `lib/class.pdf.php`.

It is a warning thrown by PHP because this function is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen posts about similar issues (I had a bunch of issues with DOMPDF), it sounds like there is other text in the output stream that's causing specifically Acrobat to reject the PDF as corrupt.

Try adding setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C"); before you call DomPDF
Take a look at this thread for more info: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=418

Comment: How are you calling domPDF in PHP? Right before wherever your initializing the class  $pdf = new DOMPDF;

Comment: See edit...I tried this and didn't get any success on PC, but I haven't checked for PHP errors as suggested in the comments above.